# How To Distinguish Between Local Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have implemented local notifications in a long-lived app.  The app runs 24 hours per day in kiosk mode.  One of the local notifications fires once per day and the other fires once per hour.  The notification that fires once per day deletes all local core data information from the previous day.  The notification that fires once per hour is a "heartbeat" for the app and creates a check in on the server once per hour.

Here is the schedule for the hourly heartbeat (it is in my main viewcontroller):

```
- (void)scheduleHeartBeat
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *heartbeat = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

[components setDay: day];
[components setMonth: month];
[components setYear: year];
[components setHour: 00];
[components setMinute: 10];
[components setSecond: 0];
[calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

heartbeat.fireDate = dateToFire;
heartbeat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
heartbeat.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:heartbeat];
}
```

I call the above method in viewDidLoad.

Then in my AppDelegate I have the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{   
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[OLEngine myEngine] deleteStuffFromYesterday:@"MyObject"];

}
```

In the didReceiveLocalNotification I need to distinguish between which Local Notification has been fired because I do not want to call the method deleteStuffFromYesterday every hour - only once per day.

How can I distinguish between these scheduled local notifications in my app delegate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `userInfo` Property to store an `NSDictionary` for this.

Store the info:

```
localNotification.userInfo = @{ @"myCustomType" : @"heartbeat" };
```

Retrieve the info:

```
NSString *myCustomType = localNotification.userInfo[@"myCustomType"];
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this with notifications?

Comment: Just added some code. It's just a dictionary which should be familiar.